# Detect when Receiver app changes from Sender

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I'm working on a Cast Sender that is intended to glean metadata from multiple Receiver apps. Is there a way to detect when an app is started on the Receiver so I can know when I can call `startSession()`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether there is a way to register a global callback, to be called  whenever any app starts on a cast device, the answer is no, there is no such thing. If that is not what you were asking, please clarify.

Comment: If there's no callback, what's the best approach? Polling occurred to me, but at the rate I'd need it the battery cost would likely be too excessive.